# Textview not updating?

Tags: android, textview

Okay, I was able to figure out a timer earlier, but now I'm having another problem

So, when I call this function called "getNextQuote();" the first time in onCreate() it updates and gets a random quote and displays it perfectly, however, when I try again, in onResume(), it doesn't refresh for some reason.

```
public void getNextQuote(){

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);//Text To be edited
    Random QuoteNum = new Random();     

    int Quote = QuoteNum.nextInt(50);

    android.util.Log.i("DebugB",""+Quote);

    String q = myString[Quote];//find which string is corresponding to the number
    tv.setText(q);//Set the Text 

    android.util.Log.i("DebugC",q);
}
```

anything obvious I'm missing???
In the log the new quotes are coming out like there supposed to, but they just arn't getting drawn to the actual emulator screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
int i = 0;

public void getNextQuote(){

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);//Text To be edited
        tv.setText("test"+i);//Set the Text
        i++;
    }
});
```

}

This counts test0, test1, test2,... :) Just put your code into that runOnUiThread. When I tried your code, I got an error (because of the thread). Also check, if your interval is short enough. Just try 1000 msec. :)

UPDATE:

Maybe this is a better aproach by reusing the Runnable (don't really know) :)

```
int i = 0;

Runnable updateTextView = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);//Text To be edited
        tv.setText("test"+i);//Set the Text
        i++;
    }
};

public void getNextQuote(){

    runOnUiThread(updateTextView);
}
```

Comment: Hello again, and thanks.. it works perfectly.. I probably should of said this earlier but I've only been programming Android for a week so I'm a huge nooooooob haha.  Thank you so much =D

Comment: Well, then I know your problem. Better ask before wasting endless time with google (like I did ^^). :)